# Compile Gstreamer/orc 0.4.32 on ubuntu1804 for arm running in rootfs using ninja occur undefined reference exception

Tags: gstreamer, ninja, rootfs

I am trying to compile gstreamer/orc on ubuntu_1804 for arm which running on rootfs my android mobile phone, but something wrong like this:

I tried some option (-j 1) to make it compile with single thread, but still not working.

[image: error info]